# Polymorphic nested_form saving in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, polymorphism

A user can create different kinds of posts. I setup a polymorphic relation.

Post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :address

  belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user_id, :postable_id, :postable_type
end
```

NeighborhoodPost

```
class NeighborhoodPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, through: :post
  has_one :post, as: :postable, autosave: true, validate: false

  attr_accessible :content, :title, :post_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post
end
```

NeighborhoodPostsController

```
def create
  params[:neighborhood_post][:post_attributes][:user_id] = current_user.id

  @neighborhood_post = NeighborhoodPost.new(params[:neighborhood_post])
  if @neighborhood_post.save
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'NeighborhoodPost was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

Neighborhood post form

```
= f.fields_for :post do |post_builder|
  .control-group
    = post_builder.label :address, 'Adres', class: 'control-label'
    .controls
      = post_builder.text_field :address, placeholder: "Adres voor locatie"
```

This actually works. However, I don't like editing params in the create action. When I try to do the following:

```
@neighborhood_post = current_user.neighborhood_posts.create(params[:neighborhood_post])
```

...it actually creates *two* posts. One with a user_id set and where address is nil one where user_id is nil and address is filled with data. How come!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your `post`, i assume you do something like this :

```
@neighborhood_post = NeighborhoodPost.new
@neighborhood_post.build_post
```

You just have to go a little further :

```
@neighborhood_post.build_post( user_id: current_user.id )
```

then in your form :

```
= f.fields_for :post do |post_builder|
  = post_builder.hidden_field :user_id
```

The drawback from this method is that you must *-ahem-* trust user input, or somehow verify that the post has a valid user_id (== current_user.id). So if you don't want to trust user input, i guess an alternative is to do something like :

```
class NeigborhoodPost < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.new_from_user( user, params = {}, options = {}, &block )
    new( params, options, &block ).tap do |new_post|
      new_post.post.user_id = user.id if new_post.post.present?
    end
  end

end
```

Then in your `create` action :

```
@neighborhood_post = NeighborhoodPost.new_from_user( user, params[:neighboorhood_post] )
```

Yet another option is to invert the process: `Post` would `accepts_nested_attributes_for :postable`, and you would create the post with `current_user.posts.new( params[:post] )`. YMMV